# How to correct PHP Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, indexing, undefined, notice

I getting error

PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  price in /home/***/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/cart.tpl on line 57

What do I have to look up to correct this error.
Thank you

```html
54  <div>       
55  <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>       
56  <?php $option_table[$option['name']] = $option['value'];  ?>  
**57 <?php $option_table_price[$option['price']] = $option['price']; ?>**  
58  <?php if($option['name'][0] != 's') { ?>  
59  - <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small><br />
60 <?php }?> 
Thank you 
61 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: should be $option_table[$option['type']]? may be wrong place there is no index "price"

Comment: You must test it with if(isset($option['price']))

Answer (score 0):

First way is check your array using [isset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php) function

```
 if (isset($option['type']))
 {
     $option_table_price[$option['type']] = $option['type'];
 }
```

Another way is [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
 if (array_key_exists('type', $option))
 {
     $option_table_price[$option['type']] = $option['type'];
 }
```

As for me, the second ways is better

Remark: Your code is unreadable, remove the extra PHP tags and make a single block of PHP code

```
<?php
foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
    $option_table[$option['name']] = $option['value'];
    $option_table_price[$option['price']] = $option['price'];

    if($option['name'][0] != 's')
    {
        printf('<small>%s: %s</small><br />', $option['name'], $option['value']);
    }
}
?>
```